# How to change the startup directory (get_ipython().profile_dir.startup_dir) for IPython?

Tags: python, automation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a jupyter/conda setup with multiple users. I was previously working with a single user and defined some .py files in the `~.ipython/profile_default/startup` folder. But that startup folder is unique to the profile/user. Is there a way for me to execute the files in the startup folder regardless of which user/profile is being used whenever a new Notebook is launched?

In simpler terms, is it possible to create a `profile_default` at Jupyter level instead of individual user level?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to set the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable for all users to point to a single location, such as:

```
export IPYTHONDIR=/path/to/.ipython
```

And then place files under `/path/to/.ipython/profile_default/startup`

Definition:

> `IPYTHONDIR`: If set, this environment variable should be the path to a directory, which IPython will use for user data. IPython will create it if it does not exist.

Source: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html#the-ipython-directory

There is a big gotcha, however; this directory must be writeable by each user that uses it. This is usually not an issue for `~/.ipython` for each user, but you should be mindful of this requirement if using a place such as `/usr/local` or `/etc`.

---

Another solution would be to use the [systemwide configuration](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#systemwide-configuration) paths, namely

```
/etc/ipython/
/usr/local/etc/ipython/
```